# Creating a new data frame using existing data

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a new data from my existing data frame "ab". The new data frame should look like "Newdf".

```
a<- c(1:5)


b<-c(11:15)


ab<-data.frame(C1=a,c2=b)


ab

df<-c(1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14,5,15)

CMT<-c(1:2)

CMT1<-rep.int(CMT,times=5)


Newdf<-data.frame(DV=df,Comp=CMT1)



Newdf
```

Can we use dplyr package? If yes, how?

Comment: Try `c(t(ab))`...

Comment: The accepted answer is not what you desired in the question. You need to be more specific in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More importantly than `dplyr`, you'd need `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
ab %>% 
  gather(Comp, DV) %>% 
  mutate(Comp = recode(Comp, "C1" = 1, "c2" = 2))
#    Comp DV
# 1     1  1
# 2     1  2
# 3     1  3
# 4     1  4
# 5     1  5
# 6     2 11
# 7     2 12
# 8     2 13
# 9     2 14
# 10    2 15
```

Comment: This is not the output they are asking for

Comment: I agree this is not *exactly* what's asked. In my own analyses, order of rows (or columns)  usually doesn't matter. When it does, it's a red flag. OP let some room for interpretation

Comment: Let me first clarify. I hate my own answer. But @AndrewGustar Already provided an answer to this question without any "interpretation" as you call it.

Comment: An answer which borrows from mine, which is fine. I'm not sure what you're implying

Comment: There's no implication. Borrow back from his answer and include order of the df (you can refer to his answer) since yours is the accepted answer. Later people will be confused with this kind of interpretations. Just a suggestion. Sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: This is bad practice. The fact that this was accepted simply makes this whole post worthless.

Comment: Sure. I can either re-use Andrew's code or delete my answer altogether, whichever suits SO etiquette best. Which do you think?

Comment: Neither, The ideal would be the OP to edit their question . And it is even more weird as they hand written the expected output. Cant get more explicit than that

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` gives you something close...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- ab %>% 
       mutate(Order=1:n()) %>% 
       gather(key=Comp,value=DV,C1,c2) %>% 
       arrange(Order) %>% 
       mutate(Comp=recode(Comp,"C1"=1,"c2"=2)) %>% 
       select(DV,Comp)

df2
   DV Comp
1   1    1
2  11    2
3   2    1
4  12    2
5   3    1
6  13    2
7   4    1
8  14    2
9   5    1
10 15    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP has asked for a `dpylr` solution, I felt challenged to look for a `data.table` solution. So, FWIW, here is an alternative approach using `melt()`.

Note that this solution does *not* depend on specific column names in `ab` as the two other `dplyr` solutions do. In addition, it should be working for more than two columns in `ab` as well (untested).

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(ab, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.vars = "rn", value.name = "DV"
     )[, Comp := rleid(variable)
       ][order(rn)][, c("rn", "variable") := NULL][]
#    DV Comp
# 1:  1    1
# 2: 11    2
# 3:  2    1
# 4: 12    2
# 5:  3    1
# 6: 13    2
# 7:  4    1
# 8: 14    2
# 9:  5    1
#10: 15    2
```

#### Data

```
ab <- structure(list(C1 = 1:5, c2 = 11:15), .Names = c("C1", "c2"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
ab
#  C1 c2
#1  1 11
#2  2 12
#3  3 13
#4  4 14
#5  5 15
```